# htaccess - add custom rewrite to standard wordpress rewrites

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i have a wordpress website
i have uploaded some of my php code at the root of my web where wordpress is installed.
i want to open those page directly.
they open if @ www.example.com/newcode.php

but i want to open them like www.example.com/newcode   (without extension .php)

the problem is when i put some .htacess code to achieve this, all wordpress pages stops and shows error404 not found and if i remove htaccess code then i cant open my own newcode.php page without extension

i tried to put this code in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but doesnt work...

this is my wordpress .htaccess (automatically created by wordpress)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

id have more files like newcode.php and some folder in which there are more code files and i want all of them to open like this

i want both wordpress pages as well as my new code page to open without any extension and i cant put newcode.php in seperate folder and make another htaccess for that specific folder

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` – that is the case for all your WP pages as well – those do _not_ exist as physical files on the file system either.

Answer (score 0):

This is [documented pretty clearly](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) - especially in this case where you don't even need any regexp knowledge. Simply replace everything before `# BEGIN WordPress` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /newcode /newcode.php [L]
```

Comment: so actually there is a ton of code in different files like some of them are newcode.php, signin.php ans some are in folders... so what should i do now?

Comment: @SidhantSood well you could start by actually adding that to your question